# How to separate path parameters with a dash in Swagger

Tags: api, yaml, swagger

I am trying to create a Swagger document with Yaml on an existing API.
In this API there is a path like this:

```
/api/foo--bar/baz
```

So I created the path definition in the Swagger Editor like this:

```
paths:
  /api/{foo}--{bar}/{baz}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/foo'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/bar'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/baz'
[...]
```

Now I am stuck with the editor telling me:

> Semantic error at paths./api/{foo}--{bar}/{baz} 
>   Partial path templating is not allowed.

Is there a possibility to express url paths like the above in swagger?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a `:` after `{baz}`?

Comment: @Anthon yes, you are right (I corrected it), but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. The error you see <strike>is</strike> [was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1303) in the Swagger Editor 3.0–3.1.5. You can ignore the error, or use the old Swagger Editor 2.x at http://editor2.swagger.io which does not have this bug.

**Update**: This bug was fixed in Swagger Editor 3.1.6 and in the online editor http://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I will update this thread if there is a fix in future.